# Refactoring plugin for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to extend the existing refactoring plugin for eclipse and want to know from where to start the work. Can somebody guide me by giving one example. 
For example :  guide me by extending the move refactoring that is already implemented, when the code runs it will display that it is extended refactoring so that i will sure that my code is running.

Comment: A place to start is this [article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Unleashing-the-Power-of-Refactoring/index.html). It's pretty old though.

Comment: @S.L.Barth this article is not helpful, i have already gone through this. I need to extend the existing refactoring using extension points kindly serious help is needed. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to contribute or modify the existing refactoring support in Eclipse, I'd say a good point to start is the corresponding project page.

Java refactoring shoul be part of the JDT core, so have look here: http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=eclipse.jdt.core